# Using Graphql and react, I am unable to access function from default export

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql

I am using graphql and react in my project but hit a snag. I am using two mutations at the bottom with a name to separate them. When I try to get createMessage from the data field I keep getting an error stating: **createMessage is not a function**. Why is this?

```
const Team = ({
   mutate,
   data: { loading, createMessage },
   match: {
      params: { teamId, channelId },
   }, 
}) => {
    <SendMessage
      onSubmit={async (text) => {
        await createMessage({
          variables: { text },
        });
      }}
    />
}

export default compose(
   graphql(createMessageMutation, { name: 'createMessage' }),
   graphql(InviteMemberToChannelMutation, {
      name: 'InviteMemberToChannel',
   }),
)(Team);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont get the createMessage from the data props. The name you pass become the name of the props. So you should do this.

```
const Team = ({
   mutate,
   createMessage,
   data: { loading },
   match: {
      params: { teamId, channelId },
   }, 
}) => {
    <SendMessage
      onSubmit={async (text) => {
        await createMessage({
          variables: { text },
        });
      }}
    />
}

export default compose(
   graphql(createMessageMutation, { name: 'createMessage' }),
   graphql(InviteMemberToChannelMutation, {
      name: 'InviteMemberToChannel',
   }),
)(Team);
```